# How to show only 3 months in datepicker as dropdown from current date and when the current month is completed then we have show the upcoming 3 months

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

How to show only 3 months in date picker as a dropdown from the current date and when the c

```js
$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    minDate: '0M',
    maxDate: '+90D'
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2">
                    Select Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="date" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Current month is completed then we have show the upcoming 3 months.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: i added my code pls verify it

Comment: Your snippet is not working

Answer (score 0):

What Datepicker library/plugin are you using? Its really hard for us to give you a solution if we don't know what you're using.

In anycase, you can disable the dates on datepicker based on today's date. This is how we can do it using Moment.js

```
const disabledDate = current => {
return (
  current &&
  current >=
    moment()
      .endOf('day')
      .subtract(number, days/months/years) //if you want to get past days
      .add(number, days/months/years) //if you want to add days
);
  };
```

Comment: i haven't used any plugins  i need it in jquery or in javascript